# TypeError: 'fn' must be callable (Prefect - Python)

Tags: python, task, prefect

I'm starting to leart some prefect + python and I'm facing a strange error at the very beginning with a very easy script:

[image: Image of the code]

I have already tried it in two diferents PC.

Comment: Welcome to the site. [Please do not post pictures of your code.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you've installed Prefect 2, but are following instructions for Prefect 1.

I recommend starting with the first steps tutorial in the Prefect docs: https://docs.prefect.io/tutorials/first-steps/

Comment: Many Thanks, thats exactly what happend, I thought that there would'nt be many diferences between 1 and 2.

How can I select your answer as solution?

Answer (score 1):

the way `with` statements work is that the variable you're defining only exists within the indented code block underneath the `with` statement itself. The end of your code should be:

```py
with Flow("prueba 1") as flow:
    carga()
    flow.run()
```

Comment: HI Matthew, thanks for your answer but I have tried your code and its still not working.
Actually the script I writed its from a udemy's course, and of course its working for the course's guy.